# Sharepoint 2013 Dispose in linq

Tags: 2013, linq, dispose

I'm wondering if this needs to be disposed or if it's a bad method to get the title of a web.

```
var currentWebApp = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
IEnumerable<SPSite> allTeamSites = currentWebApp.Sites.Where(x => x.RootWeb.WebTemplateId != 4).OrderBy(x => x.RootWeb.Title);
```

This because we get the WebTemplateId and the Title of the rootweb of a site without opening the web.

Comment: Side notes: The `currentSite` variable isn't used in this sample, and you can use `.Select(w => w.Title)` if you just want the titles.

Comment: Idd, my bad. I'll remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `SPSite` needs to be disposed

But you can handle the disposal of `SPSite` through the enumerator using the extension method (see below):

```
 static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SPSite> AsSafelyDisposed(this SPSiteCollection sites)
        {
            foreach (SPSite site in sites)
            {
                try
                {
                    yield return site;
                }
                finally
                {
                    site.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
IEnumerable<SPSite> allTeamSites = currentWebApp.Sites.AsSafelyDisposed().Where(x => x.RootWeb.WebTemplateId != 4).OrderBy(x => x.RootWeb.Title);
```

Comment: And what about the web? Since we use it also to get the properties

Comment: You don't need dispose for getting the `RootWeb` properties.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do with your IEnumerable after?

Most uses of that enumeration will re-open the SPSites. IMHO it is not good practice to create enumerables or lists of SP* objects, unless you deal with the dispose in the same scope.

You should change your LINQ to *select* into a new object with only the members of SPSite that you actually want to use. If you want to use any methods on it, you will need to revisit your strategy.